# MongoDB / C# API - How to determine if a nested document exists

Tags: c#, api, mongodb

A Newsfeed Post has a number of 'likes'

```
"Likes" : [

{
    userid: ObjectId(ae12bcd323421223),
    username: "user1",
    likedate: ISODATE(xxx)
},

{
    userid: ObjectId(ae12bcd323421224),
    username: "user2",
    likedate: ISODATE(xxx)
}


]
```

A Person can only like a post once, therefore userid/username need to be unique.

I've tried AddToSetWrapped - but it fails obviously because the DateTime is different and it adds the object anyway.  I currently have no unique indexes on the array but can change that if necessary?

How do I check for the existence of a particular userid in the Likes array and only add it if the userid does not already exist?  (either as one atomic operation, or as two operations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A Person can only like a post once, therefore userid/username need to be unique. [...]  I currently have no unique indexes on the array but can change that if necessary?

Note that unique keys don't cover that scenario. A [document in MongoDB can never violate itself](http://waistcode.net/blog/unique-array-keys-in-mongodb) through a unique constraint.

However, `Update.AddToSetWrapped` is the correct method. You could use `findAndModify` like so:

```
_db.FindAndModify<Post>(
   Query.And(
       Query.EQ("_id", post.Id), 
       Query.NE("Likes.userId", requestingUserId)), 
   Update.AddToSetWrapped("Likes", newLike));
```

This way, it will not find the post if there already is a 'like' for the given user id, and hence, won't call the update.

Comment: I actually found that Collection.Update(Query.And(EQ...NE), Update.AddToSetWrapped, SafeMode.True); worked better for my uses as I need to use the safemode parameter which isn't available in findandmodify

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `FindAndModify` also returns the document, which was not a requirement and will certainly not be faster :)